# Calculate ROI of ASIC miner

Tags: mining, asics

I am trying to understand how to calculate the Earnings over a year for an ASIC Miner.

As an example I picked the `Innosilicon A9 ZMaster`. It has the following specifications:

[image]

These specifications where taken from [Cryptocompare - Innosilicon A9 ZMaster](https://www.cryptocompare.com/mining/mining-store-5111/innosilicon-a9-zmaster-50-khs/).

I tried to calculate the ASICs miners ROI like the following:

[image]

Find below the spreadsheet where my calculations are laid out in detail:

[ASIC Miner ROI Calculations](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/162d4uqOkms-zmgRvjUd9Ja_MbTiRC7W72cHy5lkjgno/edit?usp=sharing)

Compared to the Return per year that is calculated on coincompare my calculations are not as near there:

[image]

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

I highly appreciate your replies!

Comment: Ether cannot be mined with ASIC. You're on the wrong site (try Bitcoin.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing Ethereum and Bitcoin Gold? ROI is extremely difficult to estimate as difficulty(pardon the pun) is constantly adjusting.

[This](https://hackernoon.com/how-to-mine-ethereum-in-5-min-3f3bc80d0c4b) is a good way to get your head in the door practically and you can see for yourself the practical effects of what you are trying without significant capital(unsure of g2 instance prices).